# How can I use I18N translations with ActiveModel::Validations outside of ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-i18n, activemodel

The I18n scopes provided by the Rails Guide are specific to utilization of `ActiveModel::Validations` within `ActiveRecord` objects. For example:

```
en:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      models:
        some_model:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Please enter your full legal name."
```

This won't work when using `ActiveModel::Validations` in this way:

```
class SomeModel
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

Instead the framework default “can't be blank" is used.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Substituting `activemodel` for `activerecord` fixes this and allows all subsequent scopes to work. Example:

```
en:
  activemodel: # <---
    errors:
      models:
        message:
          attributes:
            name:
              blank: "Please enter your name."
```